# Enabled RBS. Unable to access files now

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, remote-blob-storage

I followed the steps to enable remote blob storage on our staging environment. It was pretty straight forward and the blob store migrated fine.

The problem is now I can't access any file that is in the blob store. I tried running a crawl and this did not resolve it. Did I miss a step? How do I access these files through SharePoint once they are in the blob store?

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you unable to see files at all? Do you have an error when trying to upload a new file that matches the criteria for RBS?

Comment: For instance if I try to open an attachment I receive a `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` failed to load message. This happens for all files that were migrated.

Comment: Do you have access to your web front ends? If yes, try browsing to the files from the server itself. It will give you more details to the error.

Comment: If I try to browse to a file in designer I receive `Server error: The Url '' is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.` It's like my paths are all messed up now.